# Cakephp 3 Basic Authentication clarification needed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

According to cakephp [official document](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-basic-authentication) for version 3, it states to configure AuthComponent. So what I did was I added below code to AppController inside `public function initialize` method.

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Basic' => [
        'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
        'userModel' => 'Users'
    ]
]);
```

Then in UsersTable I added below code to generate new api key for a user:

```
   public function beforeSave(Event $event)
   {
       $entity = $event->data['entity'];

       if ($entity->isNew()) {
           $entity->api_key = Security::hash(Text::uuid());
       }
       return true;
   }
```

What I am trying to understand is how and where api keys gets store? When I create new user, I dont know where can I look for `api_key`.

Do I need to create a column in Users table called api_key to able store a key for a user? The official document doesnt state anything on how to access the key and use it in basic authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to create a column in Users table called api_key to able store a key for a user?

Of course. What makes you think it will be stored anywhere magically?

> The official document doesnt state anything on how to access the key and use it in basic authentication.

[It does.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems) Read the first three paragraphs. Either you didn't read it or you don't know how Basic auth works. [Look this up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). If your client uses basic auth and sends the proper information, the adapter will automatically take care of it and look the user up, this is done by exactly the code you've pasted:

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
    'Basic' => [
        'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'api_key'],
        'userModel' => 'Users'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind words @burzum. My question is not relevant to weather I understand basic authentication or not. I am trying to understand where the api_keys are stored. And thank you very much for clarifying that. However, I disagree with your statement that "Read the first three paragraphs". I dont see any reference stating that a new column needs to be created in Users table.

Comment: Doesn't address the question. This answer basically says "you didn't read the documentation, and you don't understand how it works.". Both points are probable reasons why the question was asked. The documentation vaguely references "authentication objects" and a getUser method, but fails to illustrate where and how these elements are connected.